# bash behavior on sigterm

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Have a script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# run this script.  don't run it if it's already running.
#

PIDFILE=/tmp/script.pid
LOGFILE=script.log


if [[ -f $PIDFILE ]]; then
    echo "$PIDFILE exists.  Not going to run..."
    exit 0
fi

sleep 10m >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 &
PID=$!
echo $PID > $PIDFILE

trap "echo Exiting...; rm $PIDFILE; exit $?" INT TERM EXIT KILL

wait $PID
```

Am invoking this script as below:

```
timeout 2m ./test_script
```

On timeout or ctrl+c, the script prints "Exiting" twice.

```
# timeout 2m ./test_script
^CExiting...
Exiting...
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/script.pid': No such file or directory
```

Below is the output of strace and more data:

```
# ps -ef | grep -v grep | egrep -i "sleep|time"
root      8571  4690  0 12:17 pts/0    00:00:00 timeout 2m ./test_script
root      8572  8571  0 12:17 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test_script
root      8573  8572  0 12:17 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 10m
# cat /tmp/script.pid
8573
# strace -p 8571
Process 8571 attached - interrupt to quit
wait4(-1, 0x7fffc43fad4c, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
kill(0, SIGINT)                         = 0
kill(0, SIGCONT)                        = 0
--- SIGCONT (Continued) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0)                         = 61
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x2)                       = 61
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 8572
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 8571 detached
```

Can someone kindly assist me with understanding the internals on why the script traps the signal twice to print "Exiting..." 2 times ?

Comment: `rm: cannot remove /tmp/script.pid: No such file or directory` <-- you're executing  `echo "Exiting..."` twice, are you sure you need all of `INT TERM EXIT KILL` - might it be that two of them get triggered - at the same time - when you hit CTRL-C?

Comment: that is probably what is happening. two signals being handled almost simultaneously by `trap`. As far as the script needing to trap-on all the 4 signals specified, yes I need them all. As an alternative, I am simply using the timeout from within my script. This gets around the problem of double invocation when `timeout` completes

Comment: You cannot catch `KILL`, so that one does not count.  If I run your script using bash 4.1.5 however, I am seeing only one message for `TERM` (when it does exit) and no exit for `INT`.  Perhaps the version of bash matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `trap` statement with these three lines:

```
trap "echo Exiting... INT;  exit $?" INT
trap "echo Exiting... TERM; exit $?" TERM
trap "echo Exiting... EXIT; exit $?" EXIT
```

you'll get the output

```
Exiting... TERM
Exiting... EXIT
```

from which we can deduce

- The `trap … TERM` statement causes the shell to trap the SIGTERM signal. 
  The `timeout` command sends the process a SIGTERM (by default)
  when the timeout expires. 
  So the shell catches the signal and executes the specified command,
  including the `echo`, the `rm` (in your actual script), and the `exit`.
- The `trap … EXIT` statement causes the shell to leave itself a sticky-note
  saying "remember to do this before I go home". 
  So, when the SIGTERM trap executes the `exit` command,
  the EXIT trap is executed.
- When the EXIT trap executes the `exit` command, the script actually exits,
  rather than executing the EXIT trap and going off into the recursion inferno.

If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the script is running,
you will get the INT trap followed by the EXIT trap. 
If you run the script without `timeout`, or with a timeout duration that is longer than the sleep time, you will get the EXIT trap only.

It's probably good enough to say

```
trap "exit $?" INT TERM
trap "echo Exiting...; rm $PIDFILE" EXIT
```

I believe that the EXIT trap doesn't need to execute `exit`,
because you get into the EXIT trap by executing an `exit` command
(including the implicit one at the end of the script), so,
when you finish executing the EXIT trap (`echo` and `rm`),
the shell has nothing left to do but exit. 
The only question is what exit status the script exits with. 
And, if you were saving some exit status value and doing
`rm $PIDFILE; exit $saved_status`, that might be interesting. 
But as long as you're talking about `rm $PIDFILE; exit $?`,
the script is probably going to exit with the exit status of the `rm`;
and that will probably happen by default
if the `rm` is the last command you execute.

I did some quick tests that suggested that it's possible to leave off the

```
trap "exit" INT TERM
```

command, but I don't understand that.  YMMV.

---

P.S.  As Thomas said, `trap … KILL` is ineffective.